# Corner detect takes long time to run

Tags: c++, image, opencv, opencl

I am using OpenCV’s `findchessboardcornersSB` function to find the corners in the image. I am using below code/ header file:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include"opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include<Eigen/core>
#include<vector>

namespace MAL_Vision_Dushyant {
    class ChessBoardDetector {
    public:
        int CB_Width, CB_Height;
        cv::Size patternSize;
        ChessBoardDetector(int Width, int Height) {
            CB_Width = Width;
            CB_Height = Height;
            patternSize = cv::Size(Width, Height);
        }

        //ChessBoardDetector(){}

        void get_CB_Corners(std::string filename, const bool ROI_needed = false, const bool show_img = false, const int resize_factor = 2) {
            //auto beg1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            cv::Mat src_image = cv::imread(filename);
            cv::Mat crop_image, gray_img;
            cv::Rect r;
            
            std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners(CB_Width*CB_Height);

            //crop image so that it fits on the screen. 

            if (ROI_needed) {
                //select the ROI in the image
                cv::resize(src_image, src_image, cv::Size(src_image.cols / resize_factor, src_image.rows / resize_factor));
                r = cv::selectROI(src_image);
                //resize the cropped image so that it represents pixel on original image
                crop_image = src_image(cv::Rect(resize_factor * r.x, resize_factor * r.y, resize_factor * r.width, resize_factor * r.height));
            }
            else {
                //Use original image size
                crop_image = src_image.clone();
            }
            //cv::cvtColor(crop_image, crop_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


            //bool found = cv::findChessboardCorners(src_image, patternSize, corners, cv::CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE | cv::CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE);
            bool found = cv::findChessboardCornersSB(crop_image, patternSize, corners);
        }
    };

}
```

When I run the `get_CB_Corners` function without any ROI selection, I am getting the function runtime of 4 + seconds. In my debug console project, I see a lot of OpenCL related lines. I don't know why that is necessary. Also when I run similar code in python, it takes less time than this C++ code block which is very disturbing for this basic function. Below is the main function:

```
#include"Chess_Board_Detection.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int CB_WIDTH = 9;
int CB_HEIGHT = 6;

int main()
{   
    int ang;
    cout << "Enter angle" << endl;
    cin >> ang;
    
    string input_dir = "C:\\Users\\DushyantPatil\\Documents\\Pose Estimation\\Input Data\\stereo\\images\\";
    string test_number = "test1_B\\";
    //string prefix = "1_";
    string prefix = "1_";
    string suffix = "d_6.bmp";
    string filename = input_dir + test_number + prefix + to_string(ang) + suffix;
    
    MAL_Vision_Dushyant::ChessBoardDetector CB_Detect1(CB_WIDTH, CB_HEIGHT);
    CB_Detect1.get_CB_Corners(filename, false);
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling in debug mode? Are you linking to a debug version of the OpenCV library?

Comment: Code ran in a debug mode in Visual Studio (im assuming you're using this) runs *very differently* than code ran in *release mode*. Have you tried comparing those two times?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, - I am running the code in Visual Studio nDebug mode. But should the difference be that much in release mode? Also when I run this code from terminal in ubuntu, I get the code running in 1 second. Does this have anything to do with openCL and threading? I am not sure how they affect the program though

Comment: Yes, C++ code in debug mode can be orders of magnitude slower than in release mode. Debug mode disables most optimizations. Make sure you link the release OpenCV library, not the debug one.

Answer (score 3):

The discprency in speed is probably due to the fact that both your code and OpenCV are built in debug mode. Dont worry about OpenCL calls. OpenCV optionally uses OpenCL to boost performance.

### General Review

1. Prefer functions over classes. The class `ChessBoardDetector` is not needed in this case. Instead you can just create a `findChessBoardCorners` free function that takes `patternSize`.
2. The `get_CB_corners` is doing too many things. It reads from the filesystem. Then creates a UI element to interactively get and ROI and then it crops the image and finds corners. Split this into different functions.
3. Dont import the entire namespace at file scope aka `using namespace <namespace>` is bad. The `std` and `cv` namespaces have a lot of functions. By using `using namespace std;` or `using namespace cv`. You leave your self open to name collisions.
4. Prefer `std::size_t` over `int` for indices and sizes.
5. Avoid global variables viz `CB_WIDTH` and `CB_HEIGHT`. If you want to use global constants use `constexpr`
6. Use better names. Use `chessBoard` instead of `CB`. Use `cropped_image` instead of `crop_image`.
7. Mark variables that are not modified as const.
8. Prefer commandline arguments for getting arguments for a script over `std::cin`
9. Prefer `auto variableName = Type{parameters}` syntax for defining variable. This makes it impossible to have an uninitialized variable.
10. The output of find corners is not being used anywhere. This makes the code useless.
11. Dont use `pragma once`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946730/20762025).
12. Include everthing you use explicitly. You should include `opencv.hpp` in main too.

### OpenCV Specific Review

1. From what I can understand, you are downsampling the image then selecting ROI and then resizing the images because the image is too big and the selectROI window does not fit on your screen. To get around this, create a window first
2. There is no need to default initialize `corners`. The `cv::findChessboardCornersSB` will do it for you.

### Modified Code

```
#include <cstddef>
#include"opencv2/opencv.hpp"

constexpr size_t chessBoardWidth = 9;
constexpr size_t chessBoardHeight = 6;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{   

    constexpr char usage[] = "corners [-i] <filepath> ==> where -i enables interactive mode"

    if (argc < 2){
        std::cout << usage;
        return -1;
    }

    bool interactiveMode = false;
    char * fileName = argv[1];
    if (argv[1] == '-i'){
        interactiveMode = true;
        fileName = argv[2];
    }

    auto image = cv::imread(fileName)
    auto croppedImage = cv2::Mat{};
    if(interactiveMode){
        cv2::namedWindow("Crop Image", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
        roi = selectROI("Crop Image", image);
        croppedImage = image(roi);
    } else {
        croppedImage = image;
    }

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
    if(!cv::findChessboardCornersSB(croppedImage, cv2::Size(chessBoardWidth, chessBoardHeight), corners)){
        std::cout << "No Corners Found";
        return 0;
    }

    //DO Something with corners

    return 0;
}
```